# Is there a way to set the "evaluated/not evaluated" status in SABA via the API?

Tags: scorm, lms, saba

[image: Evaluated status]

I'm currently working on an app that, thanks to some truly bad design, makes it impossible to set any sort of completion status via the SCORM package (any and all grading/completion behavior takes place outside of the SCORM package in this app).

Is there a way to set the evaluated status via the API?

Currently we set the course completion by setting the completion status on enrollments belonging to the student & course, this seems to set the entire course's status to "completed", but not the individual content/modules (I'm new to SABA so still getting a grip on the terminology).

And we know how to set this status via SCORM, but as I said we're unable to do so in this specific app.